# Add Custom Tool to Windows Command Bar With Dynamic Verb

Tags: windows, explorer, commandbar

How can I create a Windows Explorer command bar tool that takes a dynamic 
string?

I already know how to add my tool to the command bar and execute the command on click.

[image]

But I need a toolbar like the second one after *Organize*.

I need that when I click to the file name of my tool be like *My Tool - File name (selected.txt)* or *My Tool - Selected File Extension (.txt)*.

Does anyone have an idea about how to do that?

Comment: Also there must be a way of how to add an icon there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Create a shell extension. Your shell extension must implement IInitializeCommand, IObjectWithSite, IObjectWithSelection, IExplorerCommand and IExplorerCommandState.

2) Register your shell extension:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\YourCommandID]
@=YourTopCommandCaption
ExplorerCommandHandler=YourCLSID

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7}\TasksItemsSelected]
@=YourCommandID
```

If default value of TasksItemsSelected key is not empty you MUST add new string to old! For example prev value is Windows.copy the new must be Windows.copy;YourCommandID

{5c4f28b5-f869-4e84-8e60-f11db97c5cc7} is FOLDERTYPEID_Generic.

3) IExplorerCommand.GetFlags must return ECF_HASSUBCOMMANDS or ECF_ISDROPDOWN

4) IExplorerCommand.EnumSubCommands must return object implements IEnumExplorerCommand

5) IEnumExplorerCommand.Next must return object implements IExplorerCommand, IObjectWithSite and IObjectWithSelection. Every object is a single command of sub menu.

It works only on Win7.

Comment: Thanks a lot! -Is there a way to display and icon for this button? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is interesting: Iobit uninstaller shell extension doesn't register at CommandStore & FolderTypes.. that's why I though it's a hack...

Comment: @GeekUser IExplorerCommand has method GetIcon but in my experiments it was never called.

Comment: Denis, looks like you've successfully solved the issue of putting icon there (shellace library) Can you please share this secret? :)

Comment: @GeekUser Cannot confirm. Why do you think I solved the issue?

Comment: Vista supposedly called GetIcon. Now that Win11 is forcing everyone to re-implement all context menu items as IExplorerCommand for the stupid new menu we might see GetIcon getting called again...